# Prove that if $p|ra-b$ and $p|rc-d$ then $p|(ad-bc)$ for $r\in \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, divisibility

I am having a lot of trouble with this proof. Here is what I've got:

Let $a,b,c,d,r,p$ be positive.

$p|ra-b$ and $p|rc-d$ imply $$p|r(ad-bc)$$

If $gcd(p,r) = 1$, we are done. So suppose $gcd(p,r) = l$ for $l\not=1$. We then get that $l|p$ and $l|r$ imply $l|b$ and $l|d$ and so $$l|(ad-bc)$$

Notice that $px+ry = l$ for some $x,y$, and thus $pxj+ryj = lj = (ab-bc)$ for some $j$. Thus if $p|r$, we are done.

Now, what if $p\nmid r$, what can I do then? I am very stuck.

note: $p$ doesn't have to be prime.

Comment: Formatting note:  \nmid looks a lot better than "\not |"  Also, I prefer to put spaces around the usual division symbol, as I think $2\,|\,4$ looks better than $2|4$ but that's probably personal taste.

Comment: Note:  if $p\,|\,r$ then your assumptions tell you that $p\,|\,b$ and $p\,|\,d$ which makes the desired claim clear.  And:  I am assuming that $p$ is prime...though you never said that.

Comment: correct! I am still stuck on the case where $p\not \nmid r$ though

Comment: I solved that for you.  Well, trusting that you just forgot to say that $p$ was prime, it suffices to address the case $p\,|\,r$ since, clearly, $\gcd(p,r)\in \{1,p\}$.

Comment: @lulu p doesn't have to be prime. If p was prime, this would have been solved. I am assuming, however, that all the integers are positive. I tried the first few thousands using this code: [ import math
import random
i = 0

while i < 5:
    p = random.randint(1, 1000)
    a = random.randint(1, 1000)
    b = random.randint(1, 1000)
    c = random.randint(1, 1000)
    d = random.randint(1, 1000)
    r = random.randint(1, 1000)
    
    if ((r * a - b) % p == 0 and (r * c - d) % p == 0):
         print((a*d - b*c) % p)
    i=+1]

Comment: then I would edit your post for clarity.  I expect all your readers will assume that $p$ is prime.  But, yes.  the claim is true even for composites.

Comment: As in the linked dupe, simply **eliminate** $\,r\,$ from $\,ra\equiv b,\ rc\equiv d,\,$ just like in linear algebra.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relation $p |(ra-b)$ gives $ra \equiv_p b$. Likewise, the relation $p|(rc-d)$ gives $rc \equiv_p d$. Applying:

$$ad-bc \equiv_p a(rc) - (ra)c \equiv_p 0.$$

[Indeed, use $d \equiv_p rc$ to get $ad \equiv_p a(rc)$, and use $b \equiv_p ra$ to get $bc \equiv_p (ra)c$.]

Comment: Could you help me understnad why $$ad-bc \equiv_{p} a(rc) - c(ra)$$? Or, to rephrase my question, how do I know that if $\alpha \equiv_{p} \beta$ then $\alpha x \equiv_{p} \beta x$?

Comment: As per my edits in my answer, plug in $d \equiv_p rc$ to get $ad \equiv_p a(rc)$, and $b \equiv_p ra$ to get $bc \equiv_p (ra)c$.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).